# Create temporary MySQL user from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mysql

In my MySQL database I have two kind of users

1. MySQL users, used to connect and access a database directly from a client such as MySQL workbench or any ODBC editor.
2. ASP.NET membership users + roles : used to provide login for my websites.

**My situation**:

When I login via a webpage using the ASP.NET user credentials. I want to create a temporary random MySQL user (assign privileges, set password etc) and give it to the currently logged in (asp.net user) to gain temporary access to the MySQL database.

I know, if ASP.NET user has root access to create users he also has complete access to the database. My problem is, I have to give the user name and password so he can connect from another client and access the database directly. (I don't want give him root access or permanent access)

Having said he can access from another client, I would like to restrict this according to his login status in my webpage. like when he logs out of my webpage the newly created MySQL user is marked as expired or deleted.

I assume this should be very possible but I cannot think of any starting point. Could anyone help me?

kind regards

krish

Answer (score 1):

This is possible.  You could use the [create user](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html) and [grant](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) syntax to create your user and grant them privileges.

You would however need to maintain a separate table for mapping MySQL users with an expiry date.

Have you thought about a different solution?

it would be vastly more work to complete but in the long run might be a more stable / reliable and scalable solution.

Maybe create your own WCF proxy for MySQL using NET.NCP, you could then have local user accounts / temporary accounts managed by you that authorise against your WCF service rather than the database directly, the proxy would in turn would connect directly to your database.   This solution would also work from 3rd party applications.

Using a custom proxy would give you much greater control such as:

- Being able to log SQL for specific users Sanitise or restrict any
- specific command you don’t want executed on your database Not having
- your MySQL server directly contactable on the internet
- Split read & writes to different servers or clusters when scaling out

**Edit 1:** as per comments below:

I wouldn’t recommend relying on an event for the session end as this isn’t always fired.  I would suggest you create another table to manage the users and their expiry.
For example, a table that holds the user ID or username and host along with an expiration time.  This could be either date time / integer (epoch) depending on your requirements.
You would then need to invoke a query to identify all accounts from this table that have expired, you could then delete the user accounts from MySQL.

Depending on your MySQL version you could wrap a lot of the logic into a few stored procedures which will make the querying and maintenance overhead easier

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you first of all. This looks very impressive method but I'm totally new to WCF proxies or NET.NCP. I definitely would want  your solution. I'm affright that would cost me very much amount of time which I don't have right now.  For now I am thinking to create temporary user and assign privileges. my problem is when his session in website ends and loggsout how do I remove mySQL user?

Comment: I will answer this in the question body